# IIS Reverse Proxy post bytes array return Error: "The specified URL cannot be found"

Tags: iis, http-status-code-404, reverse-proxy

I'm creating a website using Vue.js, and a web service using C# MVC, hosted in IIS 10 (Windows Server 2019)

There are 3 nodes that I have created, which are:

- api.myweb.local - *for API endpoints*
- myweb.local - *web to be accessed from local network*
- myweb.com (reverse proxy) - *web to be accessed from public network. Actually it's just the same with the local network version, only limited menu and env configs. In order to reach the API server in local network, it's set up as a reverse proxy*

Problem occurs when I tried to post form containing **bytes array** to *myweb.com*.

It returns **404 Error: "The specified URL cannot be found"**.
But it works when I posted from *myweb.local*

If I remove the bytes array parameters, then it works as intended.

I checked the log files, but no information about this 404 error was logged.

Any idea what I should do?
Thanks

Comment: Try using failed request tracing to see details about 404 error.

Comment: See how your reverse proxy rules lead to that 404 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules and then the solution should be clear.